# SPROC Comment field in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

The **Comment** field for editing functions and procedures seems limited to 64 characters.

How can I increase that limit?  (Couldn't find it in the `$cfg[]` array.)

Comment: That's not a limitation by phpMyAdmin, which is just a client, but by the server it connects to. So you're looking at the wrong place. (And it might be hard wired, but I haven't found any documentation on this, so I'm not sure.)

Comment: If I enter a comment through code (using the COMMENT keyword after the procedure declaration) I can add as many characters as I like (well, there may well be a limit, but I haven't found it yet).  phpMyAdmin later displays the long comment in the Comment field, but doesn't allow to edit it.  
BTW, the underlying DBMS is MariaDB.

Comment: Well, MySQL is a master in silently ignoring parts of statements. I wouldn't be surprised if it just cuts comments off mid sentence... Check what you get back when querying `information_schema.routines.routine_comment`.

Comment: Thx, checked my routine_comments, they are all there, some of them 600 characters long.  It's just phpMyAdmin not allowing to type more than 64 characters in the box.

Comment: Just found that in earlier versions of MySQL the routine COMMENT characteristic was apparently indeed VARCHAR(64) https://www.knowledgewalls.com/johnpeter/books/mysql/how-to-create-stored-procedure-in-mysql-with-routine-comment-example.  
In later versions (e.g. MySQL 5.7, MariaDB 10.2) column ROUTINE_COMMENT in information_schema.routines is now **longtext**.  Seems like phpMyAdmin has not caught up with that.  Also, the editing box would need to be larger to allow line-breaks etc. for richer documentation.